# More detailed explanations for the db-sync-mode parameters? (i.e. safe, fast, fastest; sync, async; and nblocks_per_sync)

Tags: monerod, monerod-commands, blockchain-import

Can someone give more detailed explanations on what the various db-sync-mode parameters actually do in monerod and monero-blockchain-import, and why one might select each of them? (i.e. safe, fast, fastest; sync, async; and nblocks_per_sync)

Also, how might each parameter impact a node's CPU, RAM, and HDD/SSD use when selecting them and syncing from scratch?

Comment: i would really like to know this too

Comment: And which is the default?  And how do I set n when using `nblocks_per_sync`?

Answer (score 1):

safe: at each txn commit, the data is flushed to the disk (happens every block)

fast: the OS is left to make the decision when to flush to disk

fastest: the OS is left to make the decision, not sure the difference with fast. I think it also avoids explicitely flushing medadata, but I'm not 100% sure.

sync vs async: sync will wait for a flush to be done before continuing, while async will continue right after issuing the sync instruction, not waiting until the OS reports the operation is finished.

nblocks_per_sync is how often to request a flush. The higher the number, the longer monero will work before asking for a flush. This speeds things up, unless you start having so much queued up that you start swapping. However, it increases the danger of corruption if your database is on a flaky OS/hardware.

On a spinning HDD, actual hardware writes are very slow, so you want to keep the data cached as much as you can before hitting the disk.